# White space between jumbotron and column divs (bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I took a screenshot describing my issue. I am fairly new when it comes to bootstrap but I know the essentials. Basically, the jumbotron div (the one with "welcome") is all fine, but the columnns and rows that I create underneath don't seamlessly connect to the bottom of that jumbotron div, and is also a bit wider as well. I figure this has something to do with the grid system, as I want the text centered in the middle of the page like I have it in the screenshot.

[image: website]

Below is the relevant code pertaining to this issue.

```html
      <div class="jumbotron">

        <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>

        <p class="lead">This is my online portfolio</p>
        <hr class="m4-4">
        <p>Sometimes, it's good to think outside the box</p>
      </div>

      <div class="row justify-content-md-center text-center bg-secondary">
        <div class="col col-6 " id="about_me">
          <h2>About Me</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin malesuada
              vel nibh at efficitur. Morbi feugiat orci in laoreet luctus. Sed dolor ipsum,
              lobortis et elit at, tempor maximus enim. Donec semper est vel lectus malesua
              da posuere. Curabitur sodales tristique leo quis scelerisque. Fusce porttitor,
              diam malesuada molestie hendrerit, tellus orci rhoncus risus, id dictum nulla
              risus consectetur orci. <p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

One more thing that might be worth mentioning is that I have wrapped everything inside the container class. Including the nav bar and basically everything after the opening body tag. Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: There might be margins on either sides

Comment: check in your devtools for margin. I believe your divs in bootstrap are given extra margin by default. You can add style="margin-bottom:0 !important; to the div with jumbotron to test if that's the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple way to remove that space by using the native Bootstrap 4 classes.

Just add the `mb-0` class to your jumbotron and that's it!

The `mb-0` class means **"margin-bottom:0"**. So, it removes the margin from the bottom.

Also, to remove the horizontal scrollbar that you are getting there, add a div with the `container-fluid` class like so:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="jumbotron mb-0">

    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>

    <p class="lead">This is my online portfolio</p>
    <hr class="m4-4">
    <p>Sometimes, it's good to think outside the box</p>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row justify-content-md-center text-center bg-secondary">
        <div class="col col-6 " id="about_me">
            <h2>About Me</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin malesuada vel nibh at efficitur. Morbi feugiat orci in laoreet luctus. Sed dolor ipsum, lobortis et elit at, tempor maximus enim. Donec semper est vel lectus malesua da posuere. Curabitur sodales tristique leo quis scelerisque. Fusce porttitor, diam malesuada molestie hendrerit, tellus orci rhoncus risus, id dictum nulla risus consectetur orci.
                <p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

P.S. Using `!important` flags, in general, is not a good practice and is discouraged. Because well-written css should never need those. `!important` flags are primarily meant for quick testing, not as a permanent solution. But as I pointed out, there's no need for custom css in this case at all because Bootstrap 4 has native classes for that.

Comment: You should explain what the class does

Comment: @DarrenSweeney You're right. I just updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are margins on the jumbotron or your other div which are keeping them apart. When I applied `margin-bottom: 0 !important;` to `.jumbotron`, they got closer.

However, I do not believe this entirely fixed the issue, because the CSS for your other divs weren't provided.

```css
.jumbotron {
margin: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="jumbotron">

        <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>

        <p class="lead">This is my online portfolio</p>
        <hr class="m4-4">
        <p>Sometimes, it's good to think outside the box</p>
      </div>

      <div class="row justify-content-md-center text-center bg-secondary">
        <div class="col col-6 " id="about_me">
          <h2>About Me</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin malesuada
              vel nibh at efficitur. Morbi feugiat orci in laoreet luctus. Sed dolor ipsum,
              lobortis et elit at, tempor maximus enim. Donec semper est vel lectus malesua
              da posuere. Curabitur sodales tristique leo quis scelerisque. Fusce porttitor,
              diam malesuada molestie hendrerit, tellus orci rhoncus risus, id dictum nulla
              risus consectetur orci. <p>
        </div>
      </div>
```