# Changing the max width of Bootstrap container

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am making a login page using Bootstrap 4.
The max width of a container using Bootstrap seems to be 1140px?
My monitor is 1920px as for now. Do I have to override the value of bootstrap to be 1920px in order to make it support monitors of that size?

This is the code I am using where I want to center the content of the login form (code is just for test in order to center content):

```
<body>
<div class="container h-100 d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="jumbotron my-auto">
      <h1 class="display-3">Hello, world!</h1>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Or even for bigger monitors, should I increase the size to something insanely high (like 999999px) in order to support them?

Thanks for any feedback!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use the `container-fluid` class instead of `container` to get full width.

An even better option in your case would be to use the fluid jumbotron like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="display-4">Fluid jumbotron</h1>
    <p class="lead">This is a modified jumbotron that occupies the entire horizontal space of its parent.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

That fluid jumbotron with the `container` class above is a good option because it makes sure that users on wide 4K screens won't get mad at you. :-)

Comment: Ah, thanks! When should I use .container over .container-fluid then?

Comment: Always be very careful when using `container-fluid` because on wide 4K screens people will get very mad at you if you are doing things wrong. Therefore: Always test in dev tools (switch to mobile view and display for 4K screens) what it will actually look like on wide 4K screens.

Comment: Having said all that, I think the fluid jumbotron with `container` inside is probably what you want. Check my snippet for that.

Comment: Basically, `container-fluid` is only useful in those cases where you want a background image or some other non-essential content to fill the entire width of the screen. But don't put any navigation elements or any other text content into full width because on giant 4K wide screen that looks awful.

Comment: If you check my answer to this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48374693/white-space-between-jumbotron-and-column-divs-bootstrap/48379539#48379539 you'll see another case where the use of the `container-fluid` class actually makes sense. In that case, the user wants a dark-grey (`bg-secondary`) background to span across the entire page width.

Answer (score 2):

We can update the `_variable.scss` or we can change `container-fluid` class from `container`

```
$container-max-widths: (
  sm: 540px,
  md: 720px,
  lg: 960px,
  xl: 1440px
) !default;
```